# render() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, templates

I am getting the error "render() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" after migrating my application to new server.
Here is content of my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^warlist/', include('warlist.urls')),
        url(r'^warlist/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

and in my views.py i am doing below:

```
 template = loader.get_template('warlist/index.html')
 image = loader.get_template('warlist/image.html')
 table = loader.get_template('warlist/welcomepage_table.html')
 info = loader.get_template('warlist/info.html')
 return HttpResponse(image.render()+ template.render()+info.render()+table.render()+info_str+table_str)
```

The above application is working fine in my old server with given code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `render()`:

```
 return HttpResponse(image.render()+ template.render()+info.render()+table.render()+info_str+table_str)
```

You need to pass the context into the `render()` method.

Comment: Hi.I am new to django.Which context I have to pass in render()?

Comment: @spaceearth, context is a dict contains the value of variables used in your template html. If you have variable in your html, you can pass an empty dict {}.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `.render()` expects an argument. The `1 given` is the object on which you call the method. For instance `image.render()` will have the definition `def render(self, argument):` where the `self` is the image object on which you call the method.

Answer (score 1):

render takes something like this

```
return render(request,'template_name.html',context)
```

if you are trying to use `HttpResponse`. create one html file and the rest you want to include, include them like this `include('addition.html')` in your 'template_name.html' and then return the `HttpResponse`.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to solve this problem by passing the request as an context in .render() in my views.py as below:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def myview(request):
    template = loader.get_template('warlist/index.html')
    image = loader.get_template('warlist/image.html')
    table = loader.get_template('warlist/welcomepage_table.html')
    info = loader.get_template('warlist/info.html')
    return HttpResponse(image.render(RequestContext(request))+template.render(RequestContext(request))+info.render(RequestContext(request))+table.render(RequestContext(request))+info_str+table_str)
```

Thanks to Ke Li,Rednas and Daniel Roseman for their support.

Comment: A view should have one template - if you want to split this down into separate smaller ones, use the [include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) inside of your template